# Calculating sum of a series with negative factorials

Tags: real-analysis

In a probability question I am solving I encounter the series
$$\sum_{a = 0}^\infty {a \choose b}\frac{1}{a!2^a}$$ where $b \in \mathbb{N}_0$. However I am a bit unsure how to calculate the sum, since we have the factorial of a negative number for $b > a$. Can the sum still be calculated?

Comment: You probably mean for $b > a$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes of course, thanks.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It should be $a$ not $n$ sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original version:
$$\sum_{a\geq 0}\binom{a}{b}\frac{1}{a!}=\sum_{a\geq b}\frac{1}{b!(a-b)!}=\frac{1}{b!}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{k!}=\color{red}{\frac{e}{b!}}. $$
Updated version:
$$ \sum_{a\geq b}\frac{1}{b!(a-b)!2^a} = \frac{1}{2^b b!}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{k! 2^k}=\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{e}}{b! 2^b}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

For real (or even complex) $a$
and non-negative integer $b$,
$\binom{a}{b}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{b-1}(a-k)}{b!}
$.

This will allow you to compute your sum.

There probably is a closed form
which I am too lazy 
to try to find.